# What I need to use tensorflow on Docker without official tensorflow image?

Tags: docker, tensorflow

I want to use tensorflow with python3 on Docker without official tensorflow image (under gcr.io/tensorflow...).

I want to use `ubuntu:latest` instead of official tensorflow image.

How can I do it?

Comment: You can copy paste the official `Dockerfile` and customize as you wish: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/docker/Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

You could simply clone the [`tensorflow/tensorflow`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow) repo, go to the [`tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/docker`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/docker) folder, and:

- change the Dockerfile in order to:

  - use ubuntu:16.04
  - install python3 (before [python-numpy](http://www.numpy.org/))
- build your own tensorflow image based on those modification.